# Trying to Load kafka byte data into Bigquery

Tags: java, apache-kafka, avro

I am trying to load some few records (100 at max) from a kafka topic into bigquery .

The data stored in kafka topic is in bytes , and I have the schema avaialble in avsc file

steps I have taken are
1 consume the kafka topic for 100 messages using kafka console consumer and stored in a file
2 created a code to create a avro file , avro file consists of magic marker | schema | records
3 create a test utility to read this avro data

I am seeing invalid avro exception in my last step i have the code pasted below for creating the avro file and reading the avro file

```
public class AvroSerializer {
  public static final byte MAGIC_BYTE = 0x0;

  public void serialize() throws Exception {
    Schema schema;
    ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    try {
      schema =
          new Schema.Parser()
              .parse(
                  new File(
                      "${path to schema.avcs}"));
      byte[] kafakTopicData =
          FileUtils.readFileToByteArray(
              new File(
                  "${path to kafka topic dump using kafka console consumer}"));
      // MAGIC_BYTE | schemaId-bytes | avro_payload
      out.write(MAGIC_BYTE);
      out.write(schema.toString().getBytes());
      out.write("${output file}");
      FileUtils.writeByteArrayToFile(
          new File(
              ""),
          out.toByteArray());
    } catch (Exception ex) {
      throw new Exception(ex);
    }
  }
}
```

Trying to read the data

```
 public void decryptAvro() {
    Schema schema = null;
    try {
      schema =
          new Schema.Parser()
              .parse(
                  new File(
                      "${path to schema.avsc}"));
      DatumReader<GenericRecord> datumReader = new GenericDatumReader<>(schema);
      DataFileReader<GenericRecord> dataFileReader =
          new DataFileReader<GenericRecord>(
              new File(
                  "${path to output file created in earlier step}"),
              datumReader);
      GenericRecord hcpClaims = null;

      while (dataFileReader.hasNext()) {
        hcpClaims = dataFileReader.next(hcpClaims);
        System.out.println(hcpClaims);
      }
    } catch (Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
```

error pasted below

```
org.apache.avro.InvalidAvroMagicException: Not an Avro data file.
    at org.apache.avro.file.DataFileStream.validateMagic(DataFileStream.java:115)
    at org.apache.avro.file.DataFileStream.initialize(DataFileStream.java:123)
    at org.apache.avro.file.DataFileReader.<init>(DataFileReader.java:143)
    at org.apache.avro.file.DataFileReader.<init>(DataFileReader.java:113)
    at com.optum.clm.avroutils.AvroReader.decryptAvro(AvroReader.java:22)
```

Answer (score 1):

Avro files don't need a "magic byte", or a schema id per event. [Avro files have one schema in a header, then many records within matching that schema](https://avro.apache.org/docs/1.11.1/specification/#object-container-files). This is not possible to generate from `kafka-console-consumer`... To do this from Java, you would need to buffer Avro object instances from a plain `KafkaConsumer`, then [create a `DataFileWriter`](https://avro.apache.org/docs/1.11.1/getting-started-java/#serializing).

Besides, there already exists a [BigQuery Kafka Sink connector](https://docs.confluent.io/kafka-connectors/bigquery/current/overview.html), so you don't need Avro files on disk.